# Problem with Newton's Laws of Motion question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

**Question:** A monkey of mass $m$ moves up on a massless string so as to just lift a block of mass $M$. After some time the monkey stops moving with respect to the string. Find the magnitude of change in the monkey's acceleration.

**Answer:** $\Delta a = \dfrac{Mg(M-m)}{m(M+m)}$

I can't even understand how to begin solving this problem. Any help will be certainly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.